# what is the difference between simple_list_item_multiple_choice and simple_list_item_checked?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to use multi-choice menu I see two LayoutRes in android predefined layout for lists which for me do the same job.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddFriendActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, usersNames));
```

AND

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>AddFriendActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, usersNames));
```

what should I use If I want to implement multi-choice menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute single difference between the two is the visual style of the selected indicator that shows up on an item when it is marked as selected. The one in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` is supposedly more suited for a multi-choice selection, while the one in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` is more suited for touch-and-go scenarios. That being said, everything is relative to each and every person's taste, and moreover you could pass your own layout there to match your desired design.